# How to concatenate two values into text box in c#?

Tags: c#, casting, textbox

I have two values, I want to cast these values into a text box. The way I tried is mentioned below

```
 string time="00";
 int Result ="02";
 textresult.Text=result+' '+time;//first way error result
 textresult.Text=(CAST(Result AS varchar(50))+' '+CAST(time AS varchar(50)))//second way..syntax error.
```

I need output as 02:00 format in text box. Please suggest a way to solve this????

Comment: cast or concatenate?

Comment: int Result = "02" ? I don't think so. Get your facts straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
string time = "00";
int Result = 02;
textresult.Text=Result.ToString("D2") + ":" + time;
```

Comment: Tostring() Method with 2 Decimals..... For More Information You can check this Link....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
textresult.Text=string.Format("{0}:{1}",Result.ToString("D2"),time);
```

Your code reports syntax error because there is. It seems you are using C# like sql syntax!

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
string time="00";
int Result =02;

textresult.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}",Result.ToString("D2"),time);
```

[Fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fc7Ziw)